# Error en la programacion de un bot de discord

Tags: nodejs, discord.js

Este es el codigo

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

//Respuesta:
client.users.get("someID").send("someMessage");



// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Me da un error TypeError:

TypeError: client.users.get is not a function

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Fueguitosss\index.js:14:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Mi version de node es:

C:\Users\danie>node

Welcome to Node.js v16.13.1.

Si alguien ve el error, o en lo que puedo estar fallando, que me ayude, estoy empezando en la progrmacion. Muchas gracias.

Comment: hola! este es el sitio de Stack overflow en español. por favor, traduce tu pregunta, o pásala al homólogo inglés

Answer (score 1):

el error es uno muy basico, y la versión de node no tiene nada que ver, el error es que no pusiste `cache` en `client.users.get`, modificalo hasta tenerlo de esta forma:

```js
client.users.cache.get("someID").send("someMessage");
```

Pd: Recomiendo que si el codigo no estará en un evento messageCreate, por lo menos lo pongas en el evento ready, ya que de la forma en que lo tienes ahora puede llegar a darte errores debido a que el mensaje se intenta mandar cuando el bot aún no se ha conectado, ejemplo:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
 
    client.users.cache.get("someID").send("someMessage");
});
```